# Are there any major differences between Visual C++ and C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to make win32 apps and games. Is there any major differences between C++ and Visual C++? What should I use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual C++ is the IDE, C++ the language... Use the language you want, there is no best language...

I would go for the .NET platform if you start something new, there you can use any language that targets the platform (Managed C++, C#, VB.NET, J# ...) and interoperability with native code is great + support for DirectX is provided too.

EDIT:
You want to develop for the Win32 platform, are you serious? I would not start projects for a slowly dying platform now...

Comment: Agreed, Win32 is dying. And why would you make something with Win32 rather than use portable code?

Comment: Then what platform should I develop on? How do I port my code to run on windows, Linux, and mac os x.

Comment: Develop for .NET for example. If you really want to make it work under Linux try out Mono. Using DirectX is then not a good idea, for graphics use OpenGL instead...

Comment: OpenGL with very, very portable C (Perhaps autoconf) using GCC would make it portable.

Comment: Win32 dying? Not likely in the near future.

Comment: Why Mono? if write a C++ code from scratch, why not just use portable C++ with a good, cross platform, compiler such as gcc?

Comment: @Mohit: There's no such thing as a "game programming tutorial," but there are several books on the subject, and a number of resources at sites like gamedev.net that can help you get started. I recommend the *OpenGL Superbible* and *Game Engine Architecture*.

Comment: @dalle, not in near future, but why mess around if you can have a portable executable solution? Let the JIT do the optimizations for the platform where the code runs. For me the old way of pre-compiling for all different targets you have customers for is hopefully something that will be reduced only to very special cases. Win32 will probably really die for the customer market with the End of Customer service of Windows 7... Rumors tell that MS is considering Windows 8 to become 64bit only. But Win32 will survive for sure in virtual machine appliances :-)

Comment: @jdehaan: Sure the CLR and parts of the .NET runtime is portable. But usually when you create an application you will use some non portable components, usually dependent on some Windows specific component. By the way, Win32 isn't limited to 32-bit only, it works perfectly well on 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Visual c++ is just an [IDE](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) from Microsoft for c++, so when you program, you will be programming in c++.

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ is the IDE that uses a Microsoft C++ Compiler.

If you want a compiler but not the IDE, get GCC and make, which are more portable.